# For what $n$ does $[\log_21]+[\log_22]+[\log_23]+\dotsb+[\log_2n] = 1538$?

Tags: logarithms

I just can't solve this problem in spite of doing a whole book on logs and inequalities

> Where $[\dotsc]$ denotes the greatest integer function, what is the value of the natural number $n$ satisfying the equation
>   $$
>   [\log_21]+[\log_22]+[\log_23]+\dotsb+[\log_2n] = 1538 
> $$

A. 255
B. 256
C. 254
D. 313

The answer is A.

Please give an easy solution as I am a high school student. And I do fully understand the meaning of the question but I can't solve it.

Since stack exchange forces me to provide an attempt here it goes-
I wrote the equation as $log_2n!=1538$

after this I feel n! should be $2^{1538}  $

and now i am confused...

I hope you got your attempt for the people who put the question on hold.

nice you pointed out chris.. yeah the question is same but the person who posted it has accepted the answer to it not me!....the answer maybe sufficient to understand for him.. but it may not be for me...

PS-whats the point of giving a fake attempt and not speaking the truth?!!

Comment: The really interesting math problems tend not to have an obvious solution, at least not at first. How we solve them is often by making a guess, seeing how good (or bad) it is, maybe trying several values of $n$ in a row to see if a pattern emerges, and so forth.

Comment: i have given details of my attempts  most of my questions in Stackexchange sites... why is there such a big problem if i dont describe how i have attempted.. i feel the attempt i made was stupid so i didnt feel like describing it..

Comment: BUT still if u felt that you wanted the way i attempted it at first you should have commented.. why pjt the question on hold unnecessarily

Comment: See, now we're getting somewhere. We _could_ have had this same conversation after the first person voted "off topic", but better late than never. The boilerplate message _does_ say "any attempts you have made." Maybe what you did wasn't so stupid, or even if it was, it would at least be a starting point.

Comment: This is a _much better question_ with the added attempt. (And it was _not_ a stupid attempt!) I already cast my vote to reopen so we'll have to wait for one more person.

Comment: I see this question as pretty hard. Looking at the answer given below, it is a hard ask. There may not be a "valid" attempt made by the OP and that is why he may be shy in posting the attempt. I don't want to fight with anyone...but sometimes the attempt may just not be a valid one

Comment: thanks for supporting monk.. thats exactly the point i wanted to put forward...

Comment: The $\log_2 n!$ idea, by the way, comes to just under $1533$ when $n=237$ and evaluates to almost $1541$ when $n=238$. So it's clearly not a solution, but it comes within $10$% of the smallest choice among A,B,C,D. I find that quite interesting even though it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: hehe nice one david.. how did your calculator  calculate n!  by the way :p

Comment: I made a long column of figures on a spreadsheet in OpenOffice Calc. Basically I computed $\log_2 n!$ incrementally for every positive integer less than $240$ (at which point I saw I was high enough, so I stopped). Not a very clever method, more like dumb trial and error than anything else.

Comment: By the way, there is a procedure for asking a follow-up question when the accepted answer of an old question is missing some details you need. It wouldn't have helped much this time, though, since the "duplicate" vote occurred so late in the game. But this kind of thing is discussed on the Meta.math.stackexchange site.

Comment: ohh thanks for that info.. so then am i supposed to transfer the question to meta....incase someone points out a duplicate question and i dont like the answer of the duplicate question ? Nice method of computing $log_2n!$ by the way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact [255 is the only value that does satisfy the equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28floor%28log%282%2Cn%29%29%29%20from%201%20to%20255).  The way to make it easier is to recognize that the values you sum are $n$ for each bracket from $2^n$ to $2^{n+1}-1$, giving a total of $n2^n$. This gives $$\sum_{n=1}^{255} \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor=\sum_{k=0}^7k2^k=1538$$  It was convenient that $255=2^8-1$.  Adding or subtracting terms will change the result.  If I were doing the problem from scratch, I would do this to get the sum up to $255$ (even if that were not one of the choices), then see what correction was needed to get another.  So for example $$\sum_{n=1}^{313} \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor=\sum_{n=1}^{255} \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor+\sum_{n=256}^{313} \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor=\sum_{k=0}^7k2^k+(313-255)*8=2002$$

Added:  the reason you can't write the equation as $\log_2 (n!)=1538$ is because of the greatest integer function applied to each term.  For example, $\log_2(100)\approx 6.644$.  The greatest integer means you only add in $6$ for the term $\lfloor \log_2(100) \rfloor$.  My argument above is based on the fact that all the terms from $\lfloor \log_2(64) \rfloor$ through $\lfloor \log_2(127) \rfloor$ each contribute $6$ to the sum, so they sum to $6 \cdot 64=384$

Comment: Each step of $n$ above $255$ adds $8$, because that is the floor of the log for any term from $256$ to $511$.  Each step below deducts $7$

Comment: yeah i know my attempt was wrong.. i just posted because people wanted me to post 'any attempt'.  by the way instead of the last step why dont we just find the summation {2^k}..much easier i feel

Comment: I don't understand the question why we don't just find the sum of $2^k$.  We need to sum $k2^k$ because that is what each range of a power of $2$ contributes.  Each term contributes $k$ and there are $2^k$ of them.  For small numbers of terms, like this, it is easy just to add them up even without a calculator.  For a larger number of terms we could find a closed form similar to the sum of a finite geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

Since part of the question is, at least implicitly, "How do I attempt this?", I thought I would write about how I started looking at the question.

So I didn't worry too much about what the target number was to start with, just tried looking at a few terms of the sequence:

$$\{0,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,\ldots\}$$

with each number being represented twice as many times as the previous. So then, looking at the target number and seeing it was "quite big", I could get the sum within intervals where the value is constant, ie. from $2^{k}$ to $2^{k+1}-1$, as $k.2^k$:

$$ \{ 2,8,24,64,160,384,896,2048\}$$

(I dropped $k=0$) and clearly now I have bracketed the problem. As it happens, this is enough to solve the problem too, because the first $7$ terms actually add to $1538$, the target number, so that is reached at $2^8-1=255$.